# How to resize second cell in collectionview Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

i want to add native ads between my posts but the problem is the second cell whic is "adcell" using the same height as "cell" , how can i change the height of "asdcell" ?

this is my code for adcell

```
 collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "AdViewCell", bundle: nil) , forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "adcell")
           collectionView.delegate = self
           collectionView.dataSource = self
           view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

and to display ads

```
 let adcell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "adcell", for: indexPath) as! AdViewCell
    
      if (indexPath.item % 5 == 1){
        
        //admob code here

    return adcell
```

this code for set height of posts

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height > 960{ //Write iPhone or iPad size. If iPad :
         return CGSize(width: (((collectionView.frame.width) - 40) / 2), height: 500)
      } else { //if iPhone
           return CGSize(width: view.frame.width-20 , height: 500)
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that every five cell it goes an add cell (btw if you want to achieve this, change this `indexPath.item % 5 == 1` to `indexPath.item % 5 == 0`), then in `sizeForItemAt` you can use the same logic of `cellForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
   if indexPath.row % 5 == 0{ 
      //return size for addcell ehere
   }

   if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height > 960{ //Write iPhone or iPad size. If iPad :
      return CGSize(width: (((collectionView.frame.width) - 40) / 2), height: 500)
   } else { //if iPhone

   return CGSize(width: view.frame.width-20 , height: 500)

   }

}
```

Comment: What did not work? Show how you implemented it please